# ASP.NET Web Application Configuration goes wrong after some time

Tags: asp.net, web-config

My Web Application goes down after running for some time.  The reason is because it cannot detect certain configuration settings in the Web.Config file.  To restore it to working conditions, all I need to do is to add a space in the Web.Config and save it.  This triggers the application to be reloaded.. and with all the database settings loaded it works fine.

However.... after some time, when we access the web page again, I will be confronted with the database settings not correct error.

It is very frustrating.  Anybody has any idea how did the loaded configuration settings disappear over time in ASP.NET?

Server Version: II6 Version 6

Comment: Could you post some of the config file and some code on how you are retrieving the database settings?

Answer (score 1):

This may actually be a symptom of something else. If you manually restart the Application Pool (without modifying `web.config`) does the site start working properly?

I'd monitor the memory usage, number of handles and threads in the worker process for leaks. You may want to check if the number of database connections are increasing - some object may not be releasing them.